# unbound method must be called with instance as first argument - python

Tags: python, function, class, python-2.7, typeerror

I keep on receiving the error: `TypeError: unbound method get_num_students() must be called with Student instance as first argument (got nothing instead)`

Here is the code:

```
class Student(object):
    num_students = 0
    num_grad_2013 = 0

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, id_num, yr_of_grad, counselor):
        self = self
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.id_num = int(id_num)
        self.yr_of_grad = int(yr_of_grad)
        self.counselor = counselor

    def to_string(first_name, last_name, id_num, yr_of_grad, counselor):
        print first_name
        print last_name
        print id_num
        print yr_of_grad
        print counselor


    def move():
        num_students -= 1
        if yr_of_grad == 12:
            num_grad_2013 -= 1
        else:
            None
        print "Student with ID number: %s has moved." % (id_num)

    def grad_early():
        num_students -= 1
        num_grad_2013 -= 1
        print "Student with ID number: %s is graduating early." % (id_num)

    def get_num_students():
        print "There are %s students in this school." % (num_students)

    def get_grad_2013():
        print "There are %s students graduating this year." % (num_grad_2013)

def main():
    print "Creating student Nathan Lindquist" 
    nathan = Student("Nathan", "Lindquist", 11111, 2014, "Iverson")
    print nathan 
    print "Creating student Dylan Schlact" 
    dylan = Student("Dylan", "Schlact", 22222, 2012, "Greene") 
    print dylan 
    print "Creating student Matt Gizzo" 
    matt = Student("Matt", "Gizzo", 33333, 2013, "Connor") 
    print matt 
    # so number of students is 3, one is graduating in 2013 
    Student.get_num_students() 
    Student.get_grad_2013() 
     # change some things! 
    nathan.grad_early() 
    print nathan 
    matt.move() 
    #matt.grad_early() 
    #print matt 
    # so number of students is 2, one is graduating in 2013 
    Student.get_num_students() 
    Student.get_grad_2013()
    return
```

Here is the Python output:

```
>>> main()
Creating student Nathan Lindquist
<__main__.Student object at 0x03065430>
Creating student Dylan Schlact
<__main__.Student object at 0x030653B0>
Creating student Matt Gizzo
<__main__.Student object at 0x030653D0>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Python\student.py", line 51, in main
    Student.get_num_students()
TypeError: unbound method get_num_students() must be called with Student instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Also, if somebody could give me help with it printing the student as a space in memory, I would also appreciate it.

Comment: Your code has a number of problems.  You should read [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) to understand how to use classes.

Comment: Just add self keyword for each first argument in method definition:
def yourmethod(self, ...)

Comment: BrenBarn, I understand it has issues... this is my first piece of code with classes in it. Also, Felipsmartins, I don't exactly understand what you mean.

Comment: @Rabid_Rooster I am assuming you passed this a long time ago. So forgive me for waking up the post but I want to leave this here for the next newbie to come along. Like BrenBarn and felipsmartins said the right place to look is here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html  9.3.2.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It seems like you wanted to define `grad_early`, `get_num_students` and `get_grad_2013` as class methods, but you declared them as instance methods instead.

An instance method is a method that, well, belongs to an instance of the class.

An example would be

```
class Student(object):
    # ...

    def print_name(self):  # This is an instance method
        print "executing instance method"

    @classmethod
    def num_of_students(cls)
        print "executing class method"
```

The difference is that an instance method will work on 
    s = Student()
    s.print_name()

And a class method will work on the class itself
    Student.

Comment: new error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#32>", line 1, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Python\student.py", line 70, in main
    nathan.grad_early()
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Python\student.py", line 42, in grad_early
    print "Student with ID number: %s is graduating early." % (id_num)
NameError: global name 'id_num' is not defined

Answer (score 2):

Differences in In python 2 and 3 version:

If you already have a default method in a class with same name and you re-declare as a same name  it will appear as unbound-method call of that class instance when you wanted to instantiated it.

If you wanted class methods, but you declared them as instance methods instead.

An instance method is a method that is used when  to create an instance of the class.

An example would be

```
   def user_group(self):   #This is an instance method
        return "instance method returning group"
```

Class label method:

```
   @classmethod
   def user_group(groups):   #This is an class-label method
        return "class method returning group"
```

In python 2 and 3 version differ the class @classmethod to write 
in python 3 it automatically get that as a class-label method and don't need to write @classmethod 
I think this might help you.

Answer (score -1):

When you define an instance method, put a `self` as the method's first argument, and when you use it, add `self.` in front of your instance variable.

Like:

```
def get_num_students(self):
    print "There are %s students in this school." % (self.num_students)
```

Comment: num_studends is clearly a class attribute, not an instance (i.e. student) attribute